# webapps doesn't show up

Tags: webapps

I have chosen some of the available webapps to integrate to my ubuntu 12.10, but none of them are functioning. I tried doing this from firefox and also by installing `unity-webapps-*` directly. But I got nothing. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not really working, look at this bug:
[bug at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1068662)

Comment: oh. So it's not my fault. I feel better now.